# Как правильно создать хранилище в redux для компонента Loader?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Я только изучаю redux + react. У меня многостраничное приложение, и в некоторых используются ajax запросы на сервера для получения данных.
Компонент Loader.

```
cosnt Loader = () => {
  return (
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Как правильно сделать, чтобы не было в будущем при разработке возможных конфликтов или что то подобное.
Создать 1 редюсер Лоадера, где я буду хранить значение true/false и везде просто где нужен лоадер получать значение и диспачить или же для каждой страницы создать собственный редюсер, где будет значение статуса лоадера?

Answer (score 0):

> Создать 1 редюсер Лоадера, где я буду хранить значение true/false и
> везде просто где нужен лоадер получать значение и диспачить или же для
> каждой страницы создать собственный редюсер, где будет значение
> статуса лоадера?

Не то и не другое. Все зависит от ситуации.

Есть очень много вариантов. Я же напишу самые популярные.

Для краткости кода вместо `fetch` буду использовать [**axios**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Первый вариант. Внутри вашего компонента.

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const callRequest = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get("url");
      setLoading(false);
    };
  }, []);
```

Плюсы:

- Не засоряете глобальный state в основном ненужными true/false значениями.
- Экономите куча кода. А то каждый раз для каждого прелоадера писать `actionType`, `actionCreator` это ад.

---

Второй вариант через [**саги**](https://redux-saga.js.org/).

У вас будет отдельный `reducer` для контроля именно всех прелоадеров вашего проекта.

Пример reducer-а:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_LOADING: {
      const { ids, isLoading } = action.payload;
      const override = ids.reduce((res, id) => ({ ...res, [id]: isLoading }), {});
      return { ...state, ...override };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

И будет actionCreator

```
export const toggleLoading = (isLoading, ids) => ({
  type: actionTypes.TOGGLE_LOADING,
  payload: {
    ids,
    isLoading,
  },
});
```

Этот reducer и actionCreator мы не трогаем.И все будем делать в сагах.

Пример саги:

```
function* fetchAnything() {
  yield put(toggleLoading(true, ["anyUniqueId"]));
  try {
    // отправляем наши запросы
  } catch (err) {
    // обрабатываем ошибку
  } finally {
    yield put(toggleLoading(false, ["anyUniqueId"]));
  }
}
```

Тут у вас в сагах будет меняться только идентификатор который вы зададите для каждой саги. И потом извлекаете эти саги через [**reselect**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) и показываете в UI. Это очень просто так что думаю с этим сами справитесь.

Плюсы:

- Чистый код в проекте. Один раз написали `reducer` и `actionCreator` потом используете везде как показано на примере.

---

Третий вариант:

Через [**react-query**](https://react-query.tanstack.com/)

react-query из коробки дает контроль для каждого запроса.

Пример скопировал [**тут**](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/queries):

```
function Todos() {
   const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
 
   if (isLoading) {
     return <span>Loading...</span>
   }
 
   if (isError) {
     return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
   }
 
   return (
     <ul>
       {data.map(todo => (
         <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

Плюсы:

- Как видно с примера с react-query очень упрощает нам работу вы сэкономите куча времени и напишете более лаконичный код.

---

Выбор за вами.

Если нет возможности использовать сторонние библиотеки используйте первый вариант с `fetch`.
Иначе выбирайте один из двух. Redux-saga или React-query